# How to make Material Design drawer title become fixed?

Tags: html, css, material-design

I have built a web page using Material Design. I want to make the sidebar (`mdl-layout__drawer`) title as fixed.

Here is the picture:
[image: Desired rendering]

and here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="">
        <meta name="description" content="Introducing Lollipop, a sweet new take on Android.">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <base href="{$site_conf.site.base_url}">
        <title>{$site_title|default:"undefined"}</title>

        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="template/desktop/atah/images/favicon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="system/plugins/mdl/material.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="template/desktop/atah/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="system/plugins/mdl/material-icon.css">
        <script src="system/plugins/mdl/material.min.js"></script>
        <script src="system/plugins/mdl/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="system/plugins/tinyMCE/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header mdl-layout--fixed-drawer">
            <div class="android-header mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header--waterfall">
                <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
                    <span class="droidic android-title mdl-layout-title mdl-color-text--green-500 mdl-typography--text-uppercase">
                        {$site_conf.site.name}
                    </span>

                    <div class="android-header-spacer mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
                    <button id="d" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
                        <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
                    </button>

                    <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="d">
                        <li class="mdl-menu__item">Profil saya</li>
                        <li class="mdl-menu__item">Pengaturan</li>
                        <li data-href="/site/logout" class="mdl-menu__item">Keluar</li>
                    </ul>

                    <span class="droidic android-mobile-title mdl-layout-title mdl-color-text--green-500">
                        {$site_conf.site.name}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>


            <!-- SIDEBAR STARTED HERE -->        
            <div class="android-drawer mdl-layout__drawer non-scrollable">
                <span class="mdl-layout-title">
                    <img class="android-logo-image" src="template/desktop/atah/images/android-logo-white.png">
                </span>
                <nav class="mdl-navigation scrollable">
                {foreach from=$array_menu item=item}
                    {if $item.kd != "ds"}
                        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="{$item.anchor_link}">
                            <button type="button" class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon">
                                <i class="material-icons">{$item.icon}</i>
                            </button> {$item.anchor}
                        </a>
                    {else}
                    <span class="mdl-navigation__link">{$item.anchor}</span>
                    {/if}
                {foreachelse}
                    <span class="mdl-navigation__link">Menu tidak tersedia</span>
                {/foreach}
                </nav>
            </div>
            <main class="android-content mdl-layout__content">
```

and here is my CSS:

```css
.non-scrollable{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.scrollable{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}


.tab-action{
    line-height: 55px; text-align: right; padding: 0 2vh;
}
.list-scrollable{
    max-height: 390px; overflow-y: scroll;
}
.list-scrollable::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
}
.list-scrollable::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.list-scrollable::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}

.mdl-button--file input {
    cursor: pointer;  height: 100%;
    right: 0; opacity: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 0;
    width: 300px; z-index: 4;
}

.mdl-textfield--file .mdl-textfield__input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: calc(100% - 32px);
}
.mdl-textfield--file .mdl-button--file {
    right: 0;
}


ul.fileList{
    list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; overflow-y: scroll; min-height: 320px; 
    width: 100%; max-height: 320px
}
ul.fileList li:nth-child(odd){
    background: #eee;
}
ul.fileList li{
    padding: 0 16px; position: relative; line-height: 35px;
}
ul.fileList li .dropSign{
    float: right;
}
.block_copy{
    display: block; clear: both; margin: 0.5vh 0; width: 100%; border: none; background: transparent;
    padding: 4px 0;
}

ul.articleLists{
    width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; 
}
ul.articleLists li{
    width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 20px 0; list-style: none; line-height: 40px; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
ul.articleLists li:first-child{
    padding-top: 0;
}
ul.articleLists li:last-child{
    border: none;
}
ul.articleLists li h4{
    margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 16px; width: 100%; text-align: left;
}
ul.articleLists li h4 small{
    display: block; font-size: 12px; color: #333;
}

a.btn_pagging{
    text-decoration: none; margin: 1vh 2vh; background: #eee; padding: 1vh; 
    color: #333; border-radius: 5px;
}
span.btn_pagging{
    text-decoration: none; margin: 1vh 2vh;
}

.uploadQueue{
    margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;
}
.uploadQueue li{
    word-wrap: break-word; padding: 4px 2px; border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.uploadQueue li:last-child{
    border: none;
}

.table-no-border{
    border: none;
}
.table-no-border th, .table-no-border td{
    border: none;
}
.table-content--on-left{
    text-align: left; font-size: 1rem; 
    border-collapse: collapse; padding: 6px;
}
.table-content--on-left tr:hover{
    background: #cfd8dc;
}
.table-content--on-left td{
    text-align: left;
}

.inline-categories{
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
.inline-categories li{
    display: inline-table; background: #eeeeee; padding: 0 4px; text-align: center; 
    border-radius: 6px; margin: 2px 0;
}

.hide_dom{
    display: none;
}
.show_dom{
    visibility: visible;
}
.input-judul{
    font-size: 24px;
}
.frm_reg_blog{

}
.left-aligned{
    float: left;
}
.right-aligned{
    float: right;
}


.inliner{
    display: inline;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.label-grafik{
    width: 120px;
}
.ringkasan{
    min-height: 350px;
}
.fill-container{
    width: 100%;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: droidfont;
    src: url(../../../system/font/droidlogo.ttf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: droidmono;
    src: url(../../../system/font/droid-sans-mono.ttf);
}

.droidic{
    font-family: droidfont; 
}
.html_editor{
    width: auto; margin-right: 1vh;
}
.html_editor #inFile{
    margin: 0; background: #607d8b; padding: 4px; color: white; font-weight: bold;
}
.html_editor textarea{
    margin: 0px; width: 100%; resize: none; height: 390px; background: #37474f; color: white; 
    padding: 5px; font-family: droidmono; border: none;
}
.html_editor textarea:focus{
    outline: none;
}

.html_editor textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
}
.html_editor textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
.html_editor textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px #607d8b; 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Disable ugly boxes around images in IE10 */
a img{
  border: 0px;
}

::-moz-selection {
  background-color: #6ab344;
  color: #fff;
}

::selection {
  background-color: #6ab344;
  color: #fff;
}

.android-search-box .mdl-textfield__input {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
}

.android-header .mdl-menu__container {
  z-index: 50;
  margin: 0 !important;
}


.mdl-textfield--expandable {
  width: auto;
}

.android-fab {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20%;
  bottom: -26px;
  z-index: 3;
  background: #64ffda !important;
  color: black !important;
}

.android-mobile-title {
  display: none !important;
}


.android-logo-image {
  height: 28px;
  width: 140px;
}


.android-header {
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: white;
}

  .android-header .material-icons {
    color: #767777 !important;
  }

  .android-header .mdl-layout__drawer-button {
    background: transparent;
    color: #767777;
  }

  .android-header .mdl-navigation__link {
    color: #757575;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  .android-navigation-container {
    /* Simple hack to make the overflow happen to the left instead... */
    direction: rtl;
    -webkit-order: 1;
        -ms-flex-order: 1;
            order: 1;
    width: 500px;
    transition: opacity 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1),
        width 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  }

  .android-navigation {
    /* ... and now make sure the content is actually LTR */
    direction: ltr;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
        -ms-flex-pack: end;
            justify-content: flex-end;
    width: 800px;
  }

  .android-search-box.is-focused + .android-navigation-container {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100px;
  }


  .android-navigation .mdl-navigation__link {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 68px;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  }

    .android-navigation .mdl-navigation__link:hover {
      border-bottom: 4px solid #8bc34a;
    }

  .android-search-box {
    -webkit-order: 2;
        -ms-flex-order: 2;
            order: 2;
    margin-left: 16px;
    margin-right: 16px;
  }

  .android-more-button {
    -webkit-order: 3;
        -ms-flex-order: 3;
            order: 3;
  }

    .android-drawer {
        border-right: none;
    }
    .android-drawer-separator {
        height: 1px;
        background-color: #dcdcdc;
        margin: 8px 0;
    }
    .android-drawer .mdl-navigation__link.mdl-navigation__link {
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #757575;
    }
    .android-drawer span.mdl-navigation__link.mdl-navigation__link {
        color: #8bc34a;
    }
    .android-drawer .mdl-layout-title {
        position: relative;
        background: #6ab344;
        height: 160px;
    }
    .android-drawer .android-logo-image {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 16px;
    }


.android-be-together-section {
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  background: url('images/slide01.jpg') center 30% no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.logo-font {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #767777;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.android-slogan {
  font-size: 60px;
  padding-top: 160px;
}

.android-sub-slogan {
  font-size: 21px;
  padding-top: 24px;
}

.android-create-character {
  font-size: 21px;
  padding-top: 400px;
}

  .android-create-character a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #767777;
    font-weight: 300;
  }

.android-screen-section {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.android-screens {
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.android-screen {
  text-align: center;
}

.android-screen .android-link {
  margin-top: 16px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
}

.android-image-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.android-wear {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 160px;
  margin-right: 32px;
}

  .android-wear .android-screen-image {
    width: 40%;
    z-index: 1;
  }


.android-phone {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 64px;
  margin-right: 48px;
}

  .android-phone .android-screen-image {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
  }


.android-tablet {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 110px;
  margin-right: 64px;
}

  .android-tablet .android-screen-image {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .android-tablet .android-link {
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
  }


.android-tv {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  margin-right: 80px;
}

  .android-tv .android-screen-image {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
  }


.android-auto {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

  .android-auto .android-screen-image {
    display: block;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: 1;
  }


.android-wear-section {
  position: relative;
  background: url('images/wear.png') center top no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 800px;
}

.android-wear-band {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #37474f;
}

.android-wear-band-text {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin-left: 25%;
  padding: 24px;
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
}

  .android-wear-band-text p {
    padding-top: 8px;
  }

.android-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #8bc34a !important;
}

  .android-link:hover {
    color: #7cb342 !important;
  }

  .android-link .material-icons {
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

.android-alt-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #64ffda !important;
  font-size: 16px;
}

  .android-alt-link:hover {
    color: #00bfa5 !important;
  }

  .android-alt-link .material-icons {
    position: relative;
    top: 6px;
  }

.android-customized-section {
  text-align: center;
}

.android-customized-section-text {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 80px 16px 0 16px;
}

  .android-customized-section-text p {
    padding-top: 16px;
  }

.android-customized-section-image {
  background: url('images/devices.jpg') center top no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 400px;
}

.android-more-section {
  padding: 80px 0;
  max-width: 1044px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

  .android-more-section .android-section-title {
    margin-left: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 24px;
  }

.android-card-container {
}

  .android-card-container .mdl-card__media {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: transparent;
  }

    .android-card-container .mdl-card__media img {
      width: 100%;
    }

  .android-card-container .mdl-card__title {
    background: transparent;
    height: auto;
  }

  .android-card-container .mdl-card__title-text {
    color: black;
    height: auto;
  }

  .android-card-container .mdl-card__supporting-text {
    height: auto;
    color: black;
    padding-bottom: 56px;
  }

  .android-card-container .mdl-card__actions {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  .android-card-container .mdl-card__actions a {
    border-top: none;
    font-size: 16px;
  }

.android-footer {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  position: relative;
}

  .android-footer a:hover {
    color: #8bc34a;
  }

  .android-footer .mdl-mega-footer--top-section::after {
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  .android-footer .mdl-mega-footer--middle-section::after {
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  .android-footer .mdl-mega-footer--bottom-section {
    position: relative;
  }

  .android-footer .mdl-mega-footer--bottom-section a {
    margin-right: 2em;
  }

  .android-footer .mdl-mega-footer--right-section a .material-icons {
    position: relative;
    top: 6px;
  }


.android-link-menu:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/**** Mobile layout ****/
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .android-navigation-container {
    display: none;
  }

  .android-title {
    display: none !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  .android-mobile-title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 70px);
    top: 12px;
    transition: opacity 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  }

  /* WebViews in iOS 9 break the "~" operator, and WebViews in OS X 10.10 break
     consecutive "+" operators in some cases. Therefore, we need to use both
     here to cover all the bases. */
  .android.android-search-box.is-focused ~ .android-mobile-title,
  .android-search-box.is-focused + .android-navigation-container + .android-mobile-title {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .android-more-button {
    display: none;
  }

  .android-search-box.is-focused {
    width: calc(100% - 48px);
  }

  .android-search-box .mdl-textfield__expandable-holder {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .android-be-together-section {
    height: 350px;
  }

  .android-slogan {
    font-size: 26px;
    margin: 0 16px;
    padding-top: 24px;
  }

  .android-sub-slogan {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0 16px;
    padding-top: 8px;
  }

  .android-create-character {
    padding-top: 200px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  .android-create-character img {
    height: 12px;
  }

  .android-fab {
    display: none;
  }

  .android-wear-band-text {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 16px;
  }

  .android-footer .mdl-mega-footer--bottom-section {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

I have tried to give `overflow: hidden;` to `.mdl-layout__drawer.non-scrollable`, and give `overflow-y: scroll` to `.mdl-navigation.scrollable`.

`.mdl-layout__drawer.non-scrollable` now isn't scrollable, but the `.mdl-navigation.scrollable` it can't be scrollable.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to do it.
Just share if someone have trouble like this post

to make the sidebar navigation scrollable with fixed title i'am usign javascript to do this.

by reducing the height of the `document` using the height of `.mdl-layout__drawer .mdl-layout-title` element. and using the result as a navigation scrollable height.

here is the code :

```
document.addEventListener('mdl-componentupgraded', function(e) {
    if (typeof e.target.MaterialLayout !== 'undefined'){
        $('.scrollable').height(function(){
            var a = $('.android-drawer .mdl-layout-title').height();
            var b = $(document).height();;
            return (Math.ceil(parseInt(b) - parseInt(a))) - 20;
        });
    }
});
```

if someone have a simple or better way, write down here.

Answer (score 0):

Look for this rule in your CSS:

```css
.android-title {
  display: none !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Then update it like this:

```css
.android-title {
  display: none !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: fixed;
  display: block; 
}
```

Comment: did you mean in the drawer title?

Comment: @Bar Yes, on the div containing the title. This is the line you add to its CSS rule: `position: fixed;`

Comment: i have try in the div containing the label, it not make any change, but if add fixed to `.android-drawer.mdl-layout-title` it broke the title and still not fixed

Comment: @Bar Can I see your CSS?

Comment: here is the picture
http://imgur.com/a/KlTzV still not work the drawer title isn't fixed

Comment: it still not work, i think you wrong about the class, it not `.android-title` but `.android-drawer .mdl-layout-title`  i have try in this too but it not work

Comment: @Bar Is the title inside a span tag? If so, try changing it to a div and try my answer again. If that doesn't work, I don't know what's wrong

Comment: @Bar I'm sorry, I tried everything I could think of. I hope you find the answer